# Add existing data to Infopath Form Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a Sharepoint Form Library and a Infopath associated with it. The form (Employee New Hire)contains employee name,address , designation etc fields. Once the new employee joins,the form submits all the data respective field in the form library.
Now i have list of old employees, who joined the company earlier. They do not have not have there data in the SharePoint Form Library. Rather it is in an excel form. How can I map existing employee info in excel to my new Form Library? So that I can have a infopath option for existing employees too?
Please suggest.